# JQuery: Populate two table rows base in the cell data

Tags: jquery

Both dbCount and dbPercentage come from the database. The rest of the objects in the table are from a static file. i want to populate each row with the right dbCount and dbPercentage. The code i have below populate every row with the same dbCount and dbPercentage. Please Help!

```
            $.each(finalAccepted, function (key, obj) {
                //if (finalSelected) {
                var row = $("<tr />")
                $("#here_table").append(row);
                //row.append($("<td>" + obj.NIN + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + obj.NOM + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + obj.PRENOM + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + obj.SEXE + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + obj.PARTIPOLITIQUE + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + obj.DECISION + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + obj.CIRCONSCRIPTION + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + dbCount + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + dbPercentage + "</td>"));
                $("<td>").html('<input id="chkbox"   type="checkbox"/>').appendTo(row) + "</td>";
                $('.candidate-info-detail-container').show();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

dbCount and dbPercentage are defined where? are they set for every row? Don't think so.
You should populate your dbCount and dbPercentage fields in your json object like the other fields:

```
$.each(finalAccepted, function (key, obj) {
            //if (finalSelected) {
            var row = $("<tr />")
            $("#here_table").append(row);
            //row.append($("<td>" + obj.NIN + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + obj.NOM + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + obj.PRENOM + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + obj.SEXE + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + obj.PARTIPOLITIQUE + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + obj.DECISION + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + obj.CIRCONSCRIPTION + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + **obj.dbCount** + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + **obj.dbPercentage** + "</td>"));
            $("<td>").html('<input id="chkbox"   type="checkbox"/>').appendTo(row) + "</td>";
            $('.candidate-info-detail-container').show();
        });
```

Comment: they are defined as global. I want to know if there is was i can match them with only the cell in the table containing the name.

Comment: You should  add the values to the json object in the back-end. This way, you would have nothing to do in the front-end

Comment: you mean read the JSON object from the disc, update the correspondent field in the JSON object? How to do that?